# Execute MySQL Stored Procedure using Command Line

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, command-line

Please help me out to execute a MySQL Stored procedure  in command line, where the procedure contains conditional statements..

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
$ mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password db_name

mysql> call stored_procedure_name();
```

or

```
$ mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password db_name < script.sql
```

where `script.sql` contains your sql statement:

```
call stored_procedure_name();
```

Answer (score 22):

Or:

```
mysql --user=your_username --execute="call stored_procedure_name()" db_name
```

The same as:

```
mysql ...  -e "call stored_procedure_name()" ...
```

Comment: This also allows you to type/paste in your password rather than leaving it in the command history. Just add -p or --password but don't put the password on the command line, you'll get prompted for it. (also saves escaping the password if it's a nasty random one)

Answer (score 6):

Or if you don't want to create a .sql file:

```
$ mysql -u your_username --password=your_password db_name <<!!
call stored_procedure_name();
!!
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have parameters,

```
call stored_procedure_name(intValue, doubleValue, 'dateValue');
```

If your stored procedure doesnot take parameters,

```
call stored_procedure_name();
```