# Command for executing the MySQL stored procedures using command prompt

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, command-prompt

Command for executing the MySQL stored procedures using command prompt also required to reduce the size of output history on a console window.

Comment: This question is [partly a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828341/execute-mysql-stored-procedure-using-command-line)

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**
There is already a [similar question with excellent answers on the CALL'ing part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828341/execute-mysql-stored-procedure-using-command-line).

To run stored procedures from the command line, use the -e option of the `mysql` client. Example, to call a SP "foo", from bash, you'd do:

```
bash> mysql -e "call foo()" dbname
```

If you do not want the command to be stored in the history file, add a space before the mysql command, thusly:

```
bash>  mysql -e "call foo()" dbname
      ^
      |_ space
```

Comment: Been a while that I've been bashing around. But huh, that trick with the space is actually [a thing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115917/why-is-bash-not-storing-commands-that-start-with-spaces). The things you learn at SO.